# Why there are so many .dSYM files and how to identify the correct one?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to get .dSYM files from my archive, by this way:

```
- Right click on an archive
- Show in Finder
- Right click > Show Package Contents
- Navigate to dSYMS folder
```

I find there are so many dSYM files inside.

[image]

How can I identify which dSYM that I can use for my crash?

Comment: That's not so normal...